# Populating one combobox from another using ASP.NET and KnockoutJS

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, combobox

I know it has been asked before, but it I've been at it for hours and I couldn't find a viable solution. Summarising, I receive an JSON string from the Server (C#), like this:

```
function CallFromServer() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "Default.aspx/GetTest",
    data: "{ }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
            locationsList = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
        }
    });
};
```

Pretty vanilla, right? Each entry of locationsList consists of a string, which is a state and another list, consisting of the cities in this given state. I'm pretty new to KnockoutJS (and it's not even my project, I'm just doing a small freelance), so after messing around for a while, I came to this conclusion on how to populate comboboxes:

HTML:

```
<select id="stateSelect" onchange="GetCities()" style="background-color:#69bed2; width:50px;" data-placeholder="..."
        data-bind="options: stateValue" name="state" class="chosen-select" tabindex="1">
</select>

<select id="citySelect" style="background-color:#69bed2; width:143px;" data-placeholder="Select a state"
              data-bind="options: cityValue" name="city" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">
</select>
```

JS:

```
function CalculatorViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    CallFromServer(); //Mine
    GetStates(); //Mine

    self.percentBonus = ko.observable(3);
    self.typedValue = ko.observable("0");
    self.bonusValue = ko.observable('');
    self.messageValue = ko.observable("");
    self.stateValue = ko.observableArray(stateArray); //Mine
    self.cityValue = ko.observableArray(cityArray); //Mine

    (...) //A lot of stuff
}
```

What isn't commented as "Mine" was pretty much there already and along with some reading of the KOJS documentation, I used it in order to try to achieve what I wanted.

Ok, now let's get to the gist of it. One might notice that I used

```
onchange="GetCities()
```

in the first select. Here's it's code:

```
function GetCities() {
    cityArray.clear();
    cityArray[0] = '';
    var currentState = $('#stateSelect :selected').text();
    $.each(locationsList, function (i, e) {
        if (e.stateName == currentState) {
            $.each(e.cityList, function (j, city) {
                cityArray[j] = e.cityList[j].cityName;
            });
        }
    });
};
```

As espected, whenever this onChange event is raised when a state is changed, self.cityArray updates itself to the proper value. However, the combobox to which it is bound won't refresh, no matter what. I've read a lot about different ways to do it, but I feel that I'm so close with this approach that starting from scratch is not an option.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm missing here?

BTW, don't worry about my stateArray binding, it works just fine. RENDERING the new set of options provided by the cityArray after selecting a state is what is proving to be troublesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused as to how Knockout works, it may help going through [the turorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/). You seem to be doing two things that go against the idea of KO that are part of your problem:

- don't directly wire the `onchange` event like that, but use some Knockout construct (for example a subscription) for that;
- you seem to be clearing and repopulating the `cityArray` instead of the `cityValue` observable array; the UI will only respond to changes in the latter

Furthermore, you'll need:

- a `selectedOptions` binding to bind an observable to the selected state(s)

Some changes I'd at least suggest, in respective order:

```html
<select id="stateSelect" 
        style="background-color:#69bed2; width:50px;" 
        data-placeholder="..."
        data-bind="options: stateValue, selectedOptions: selectedStates" 
        name="state" 
        class="chosen-select" 
        tabindex="1">
</select>
```

The view model needs to be extended with something to hold the selection of states:

```
function CalculatorViewModel()
{
    // Added:
    self.selectedStates = ko.observableArray([]);;       
}
```

Also remove the `onchange` direct event wiring. Replace it by something along these lines, subscribing to the selectedOptions:

```
// Use a KO subscription:
self.selectedStates .subscribe(function(newStateValue) {

    // Clear the *observable* array
    self.cityValues.removeAll();

    $.each(locationsList, function (i, e) {
        if (e.stateName == newStateValue) {
            $.each(e.cityList, function (j, city) {
                // Push into the observable array so the UI gets updated
                self.cityValues.push(e.cityList[j].cityName);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGDtA/1/) to demo how this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeroen, this project has been delivered to me with a very short deadline, so I couldn't properly study KO, I sort of had to do everything as quickly as I could. I'll try your suggestion once I get home from work and I'll give you a somewhat more insightful feedback.

Comment: Sure thing! By the way, the tutorials for KO are very good and compact, at about 1 hour paying for themselves at I'd estimate *within 4 hrs of working with KO*.

Comment: Hello Jeroen. I've tried what you told me to no avail. I've read a bit further about observables and now I'm actually aware of what I'm doing (sort of). I have also read about subscribe, which really seems to be the way to go. However, for some reason, the observableArray stateValue isn't detecting the changes. Even something as simple as     
    self.stateValue.subscribe(function () {
        alert('yeah!');
    }); won't work. Unfortunatelly I don't have time to go through the tutorials right now, so would you have any idea of why it behaves like this?

Comment: @S.O. Ahhh yes I made a slight mistake. You'll need a `selectedOptions` binding. I've updated my answer and added a fiddle as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I already deleted the other question and I'll try it again. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Jeroen, you're a frikkin' life saver. It didn't work right away, but that's because it was conflicting with the Chosen jQuery plugin the designer decided to use to style the combo boxes (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Once again, many thanks, if I could upvote you more than once, I would.